# how to move Javascript created DIV to bottom of page

Tags: javascript, html, swagger, swagger-ui

I have [swagger ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist) HTML page. there is generating HTML tags and divs with javascript

so I want to move this whole description div to the bottom of the page.
but there are [13 000 lines of javascript](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/dist/swagger-ui.js) how can I find out what needs to change?

[image]

[image]

Comment: but you still have coordinates to select that element... maybe you could just run your own javascript `.querySelector('.description')` and change its position on document ready? or you could just add a css rules in your styles so that element will have a `position: absolute;bottom:0` or sticky or something like that depending on if you have parent position relative or not.

Comment: I found that .description div.renderedMarkdown is exactly what I want to move but if I set this position: absolute it goes under the body and if I set it relative it goes after the body but is not responsive.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding right, you don't know how to find what to change because there are so many lines. You should use Chrome Developer Tools.

You must right click > inspect the part you want to move to the bottom of the page. Then you can search (CTRL + F) for a spesific part of the code and find what you need.

Here is a more cleaner explanation.

[https://nira.com/chrome-developer-tools/#:~:text=From%20the%20Chrome%20menu%3A,web%20page%20you're%20on](https://nira.com/chrome-developer-tools/#:%7E:text=From%20the%20Chrome%20menu%3A,web%20page%20you%27re%20on).

Finally you can make the change you need.

Comment: I found that .description div.renderedMarkdown is exactly what I want to move but if I set this position: absolute it goes under the body and if I set it relative it goes after the body but is not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to be fixed at bottom of the page You can simply add this css

```
body {
   padding-bottom:52px;
}

 .description{
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
}
```